# Adding admob or mobclix to wiengine android app

Tags: android, integration, ads, cocos2d-android

I'm trying to implement some mobclix ads into an android app based on wiengine which is basically a java port of cocos2d. Has anyone tried doing this? if so please tell me how ;)

To be clear the basic problem is that because wiengine uses a nonstandard View based class (WYGLSurfaceView) you can't easily add another ad View on top of the existing one.

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Activity.addContentView, samples:

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
    lp.bottomMargin = 10;
AdView ad = new AdView(this);
ad.setResId("xxx");
ad.setGoneIfFail(true);
addContentView(ad, lp);
ad.requestAd();
```

full answer: http://blog.wiyun.com/?cat=8

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not sure if it will answer your question but we can push a new activity:

```
Intent toInfoIntent = new Intent(Director.getInstance().getContext(), InfoActivity.class);
Director.getInstance().getContext().startActivity(toInfoIntent);
```